# Trying to understand ESP32 OTA over the GSM code

Tags: arduino, gsm, esp32, ota

I am performing ESP32 OTA over the GSM. I have found some example code online, modified it slightly based on my board connections and was able to sucesfully perform a firmware update.

I use lilygo ESP32 GSM development board.

However, it frustrates me that I am not capable of understanding what really happens in the code at the low level. I really want to understand before I go any further with my project.

Full code for my OTA update:

```
#include <Update.h>
#define TINY_GSM_MODEM_SIM800
// Increase RX buffer
#define TINY_GSM_RX_BUFFER 1030

const char apn[] = "omnitel";
const char user[] = "omni";
const char pass[] = "omni";



#define MODEM_RST             5
#define MODEM_PWRKEY          4
#define MODEM_POWER_ON       23
#define MODEM_TX             27
#define MODEM_RX             26
#define LED_GPIO             13
#define LED_ON               HIGH
#define LED_OFF              LOW


#define SerialAT  Serial1

#include <TinyGsmClient.h>
#include <CRC32.h>

#include "FS.h"
#include "SPIFFS.h"

#ifdef DUMP_AT_COMMANDS
#include <StreamDebugger.h>
StreamDebugger debugger(SerialAT, Serial);
TinyGsm modem(debugger);
#else
TinyGsm modem(SerialAT);
#endif


TinyGsmClient client(modem);

const char server[] = "myesptestserver.ddns.net";
const int port = 80;
const char resource[] = "/esp.bin"; //here de bin file

uint32_t knownCRC32 = 0x6f50d767;
uint32_t knownFileSize = 1024; // In case server does not send it

void setup()
{
    SerialAT.begin(115200, SERIAL_8N1, MODEM_RX, MODEM_TX);
    // Set console baud rate
    Serial.begin(115200);

    setupModem();
    delay(10);

    if (!SPIFFS.begin(true))
    {
        Serial.println("SPIFFS Mount Failed");
        return;
    }
    SPIFFS.format();
    listDir(SPIFFS, "/", 0);

    // Set GSM module baud rate
    
    delay(3000);

    // Restart takes quite some time
    // To skip it, call init() instead of restart()
    Serial.println("Initializing modem...");
    modem.restart();

    String modemInfo = modem.getModemInfo();
    Serial.print("Modem: ");
    Serial.println(modemInfo);

    // Unlock your SIM card with a PIN
    //modem.simUnlock("1234");
}



void loop()
{
    Serial.print("Waiting for network...");
    if (!modem.waitForNetwork())
    {
        Serial.println(" fail");
        delay(10000);
        return;
    }
    Serial.println(" OK");

    Serial.print("Connecting to ");
    Serial.print(apn);
    if (!modem.gprsConnect(apn, user, pass))
    {
        Serial.println(" fail");
        delay(10000);
        return;
    }
    Serial.println(" OK");

    Serial.print("Connecting to ");
    Serial.print(server);

    // if you get a connection, report back via serial:
    if (!client.connect(server, port))
    {
        Serial.println(" fail");
        delay(10000);
        return;
    }
    Serial.println(" OK");
    
    // Make a HTTP request:
    client.print(String("GET ") + resource + " HTTP/1.0\r\n");
    client.print(String("Host: ") + server + "\r\n");
    client.print("Connection: close\r\n\r\n");

    long timeout = millis();
    while (client.available() == 0)
    {
        if (millis() - timeout > 5000L)
        {
            Serial.println(">>> Client Timeout !");
            client.stop();
            delay(10000L);
            return;
        }
    }

    Serial.println("Reading header");
    uint32_t contentLength = knownFileSize;

    File file = SPIFFS.open("/update.bin", FILE_APPEND);


    while (client.available())
    {
        String line = client.readStringUntil('\n');
        line.trim();
        //Serial.println(line);    // Uncomment this to show response header
        line.toLowerCase();
        if (line.startsWith("content-length:"))
        {
            contentLength = line.substring(line.lastIndexOf(':') + 1).toInt();
        }
        else if (line.length() == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
    }


    timeout = millis();
    uint32_t readLength = 0;
    CRC32 crc;

    unsigned long timeElapsed = millis();
    printPercent(readLength, contentLength);
    

    while (readLength < contentLength && client.connected() && millis() - timeout < 10000L)
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (client.available())
        {
                // read file data to spiffs
            if (!file.print(char(client.read())))
            {
                Serial.println("Appending file");
            }
            //Serial.print((char)c);       // Uncomment this to show data
            //crc.update(c);
            readLength++;

            if (readLength % (contentLength / 13) == 0)
            {
                printPercent(readLength, contentLength);
            }
            timeout = millis();
        }
    }

    file.close();

    printPercent(readLength, contentLength);
    timeElapsed = millis() - timeElapsed;
    Serial.println();

    client.stop();
    Serial.println("stop client");

    modem.gprsDisconnect();
    Serial.println("gprs disconnect");
    Serial.println();

    float duration = float(timeElapsed) / 1000;
  /*
    Serial.print("Tamaño de Archivo: ");
    Serial.println(contentLength);
    Serial.print("Leido:  ");
    Serial.println(readLength);
    Serial.print("Calculado. CRC32:    0x");
    Serial.println(crc.finalize(), HEX);
    Serial.print("Conocido CRC32:    0x");
    Serial.println(knownCRC32, HEX);
    Serial.print("Bajado en:       ");
    Serial.print(duration);
    Serial.println("s");

    Serial.println("Se genera una espera de 3 segundos");
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        Serial.print(String(i) + "...");
        delay(1000);
    }
  */
    //readFile(SPIFFS, "/update.bin");

    updateFromFS();

    // Do nothing forevermore
    while (true)
    {
        delay(1000);
    }
}







void appendFile(fs::FS &fs, const char *path, const char *message)
{
    Serial.printf("Appending to file: %s\n", path);

    File file = fs.open(path, FILE_APPEND);
    if (!file)
    {
        Serial.println("Failed to open file for appending");
        return;
    }
    if (file.print(message))
    {
        Serial.println("APOK");
    }
    else
    {
        Serial.println("APX");
    }
}

void readFile(fs::FS &fs, const char *path)
{
    Serial.printf("Reading file: %s\n", path);

    File file = fs.open(path);
    if (!file || file.isDirectory())
    {
        Serial.println("Failed to open file for reading");
        return;
    }

    Serial.print("Read from file: ");
    while (file.available())
    {
        Serial.write(file.read());
        delayMicroseconds(100);
    }
}

void writeFile(fs::FS &fs, const char *path, const char *message)
{
    Serial.printf("Writing file: %s\n", path);

    File file = fs.open(path, FILE_WRITE);
    if (!file)
    {
        Serial.println("Failed to open file for writing");
        return;
    }
    if (file.print(message))
    {
        Serial.println("File written");
    }
    else
    {
        Serial.println("Write failed");
    }
}

void listDir(fs::FS &fs, const char *dirname, uint8_t levels)
{
    Serial.printf("Listing directory: %s\n", dirname);

    File root = fs.open(dirname);
    if (!root)
    {
        Serial.println("Failed to open directory");
        return;
    }
    if (!root.isDirectory())
    {
        Serial.println("Not a directory");
        return;
    }

    File file = root.openNextFile();
    while (file)
    {
        if (file.isDirectory())
        {
            Serial.print("  DIR : ");
            Serial.println(file.name());
            if (levels)
            {
                listDir(fs, file.name(), levels - 1);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Serial.print("  FILE: ");
            Serial.print(file.name());
            Serial.print("  SIZE: ");
            Serial.println(file.size());
        }
        file = root.openNextFile();
    }
}

void deleteFile(fs::FS &fs, const char *path)
{
    Serial.printf("Deleting file: %s\n", path);
    if (fs.remove(path))
    {
        Serial.println("File deleted");
    }
    else
    {
        Serial.println("Delete failed");
    }
}

void updateFromFS()
{
    File updateBin = SPIFFS.open("/update.bin");
    if (updateBin)
    {
        if (updateBin.isDirectory())
        {
            Serial.println("Directory error");
            updateBin.close();
            return;
        }

        size_t updateSize = updateBin.size();

        if (updateSize > 0)
        {
            Serial.println("Starting update");
            performUpdate(updateBin, updateSize);
        }
        else
        {
            Serial.println("Error, archivo vacío");
        }

        updateBin.close();

        // whe finished remove the binary from sd card to indicate end of the process
        //fs.remove("/update.bin");
    }
    else
    {
        Serial.println("no such binary");
    }
}

void performUpdate(Stream &updateSource, size_t updateSize)
{
    if (Update.begin(updateSize))
    {
        size_t written = Update.writeStream(updateSource);
        if (written == updateSize)
        {
            Serial.println("Writes : " + String(written) + " successfully");
        }
        else
        {
            Serial.println("Written only : " + String(written) + "/" + String(updateSize) + ". Retry?");
        }
        if (Update.end())
        {
            Serial.println("OTA finished!");
            if (Update.isFinished())
            {
                Serial.println("Restart ESP device!");
                ESP.restart();
            }
            else
            {
                Serial.println("OTA not fiished");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Serial.println("Error occured #: " + String(Update.getError()));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Serial.println("Cannot beggin update");
    }
}





void printPercent(uint32_t readLength, uint32_t contentLength)
{
    // If we know the total length
    if (contentLength != -1)
    {
        Serial.print("\r ");
        Serial.print((100.0 * readLength) / contentLength);
        Serial.print('%');
    }
    else
    {
        Serial.println(readLength);
    }
}



void setupModem()
{
#ifdef MODEM_RST
    // Keep reset high
    pinMode(MODEM_RST, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(MODEM_RST, HIGH);
#endif

    pinMode(MODEM_PWRKEY, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(MODEM_POWER_ON, OUTPUT);

    // Turn on the Modem power first
    digitalWrite(MODEM_POWER_ON, HIGH);

    // Pull down PWRKEY for more than 1 second according to manual requirements
    digitalWrite(MODEM_PWRKEY, HIGH);
    delay(100);
    digitalWrite(MODEM_PWRKEY, LOW);
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(MODEM_PWRKEY, HIGH);

    // Initialize the indicator as an output
    pinMode(LED_GPIO, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(LED_GPIO, LED_OFF);
}
```

From what I understand, the following part of the code reads my binary file that is stored in the server and read it into SPIFFS memory:

```
    while (readLength < contentLength && client.connected() && millis() - timeout < 10000L)
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (client.available())
        {
                // read file data to spiffs
            if (!file.print(char(client.read())))
            {
                Serial.println("Appending file");
            }
            //Serial.print((char)c);       // Uncomment this to show data
            //crc.update(c);
            readLength++;

            if (readLength % (contentLength / 13) == 0)
            {
                printPercent(readLength, contentLength);
            }
            timeout = millis();
        }
    }
```

Then the updateFromFS() function is executed, which checks whether the binary is all good and then calls another function performUpdate(updateBin, updateSize);

```
void updateFromFS()
{
    File updateBin = SPIFFS.open("/update.bin");
    if (updateBin)
    {
        if (updateBin.isDirectory())
        {
            Serial.println("Directory error");
            updateBin.close();
            return;
        }

        size_t updateSize = updateBin.size();

        if (updateSize > 0)
        {
            Serial.println("Starting update");
            performUpdate(updateBin, updateSize);
        }
        else
        {
            Serial.println("Error, archivo vacío");
        }

        updateBin.close();

        // whe finished remove the binary from sd card to indicate end of the process
        //fs.remove("/update.bin");
    }
    else
    {
        Serial.println("no such binary");
    }
}
```

in the performUpdate(updateBin, updateSize), 2 functions from Arduino **Update** Library are being called ( Update.begin(updateSize) and Update.writeStream(updateSource) ) and that is where I cant follow anymore...

```
void performUpdate(Stream &updateSource, size_t updateSize)
{
    if (Update.begin(updateSize))
    {
        size_t written = Update.writeStream(updateSource);
        if (written == updateSize)
        {
            Serial.println("Writes : " + String(written) + " successfully");
        }
        else
        {
            Serial.println("Written only : " + String(written) + "/" + String(updateSize) + ". Retry?");
        }
        if (Update.end())
        {
            Serial.println("OTA finished!");
            if (Update.isFinished())
            {
                Serial.println("Restart ESP device!");
                ESP.restart();
            }
            else
            {
                Serial.println("OTA not fiished");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Serial.println("Error occured #: " + String(Update.getError()));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Serial.println("Cannot beggin update");
    }
}
```

I have found this Update library source code :
https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/libraries/Update/src/Updater.cpp

But it seems that this is beyond my knowledge to understand what really is going on in this code.

First of all, we pass only 1 variable to .begin method, but the function prototype requires more than that:

```
bool UpdateClass::begin(size_t size, int command, int ledPin, uint8_t ledOn, const char *label)
```

And then I am trying to understand what happens in function Update.writeStream(updateSource) but cant..

If anyone could shed some light here I would appreciate a lot! Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm downloads the new firmware (.bin) from the cloud to the device's local memory and makes the firmware change with the UpdateClass library
(I see the texts in Spanish if you want we speak in Spanish)

Check the .h (only one argument required)

https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/libraries/Update/src/Update.h

```
/*
      Call this to check the space needed for the update
      Will return false if there is not enough space
*/
bool begin(size_t size=UPDATE_SIZE_UNKNOWN, int command = U_FLASH, int ledPin = -1, uint8_t ledOn = LOW, const char *label = NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the OTAdrive library and use it for OTA updates.
Check here for the [esp32 gsm modem OTA](https://otadrive.com/blog/ESP32_SIM800_OTA) example.